# JQuery UI Page Loading Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I get this error when I try to use the JQuery UI library ***"TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function"*** 
and the dialog doesn't work while I load those libraries

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

I searched for that and someone says that this happens because "you load both jQuery and jQuery UI in your project" , but I am in need for both of them.

So has anyone been experienced with such error to help me? .

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add

> jquery.ui.core.min.js

This is probably creating a conflict with

> jquery-ui-1.11.2.js

As you can see here: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I solved it, it was the jquery library wasn't compatible with the ui library. I found a compatible library. Thanks for help